# Use attribute or selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Which is better to select textbox:

`input[type=text]` or `input:text`

Which to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest:

```
$('input:text')
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember you can also do

```
$(':text')
```

Although this is not recommended by [the manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/text).

Comment: Only time you'd want to do this is if you were filtering something that was already made up of all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Internet Explorer does not support

```
input[type=text]
```

CSS selector, but it will work on JQuery. The simplest, is, of course

```
:text
```